# Spring MVC: what is the XML equivalent of @RequestMapping per method mapping?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Given this simple controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("succeed");
    }
}
```

What could be it's xml equivalent?
I have read [here](https://spring.io/blog/2008/03/24/using-a-hybrid-annotations-xml-approach-for-request-mapping-in-spring-mvc) that since Spring 2.5 it is possible to use @RequestMapping annotation for URL-to-Controller mappings, which can be placed on a class or a method. I wonder if it is possible to map a method within a xml configuration file. I've had a hard time finding information regarding this possibility

Comment: There isn't a replacement. You would have to write a controller per method you would normally have and use a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` to map to that controller.

Comment: What do you mean for "a controller per method?"
That I will have to make a Java class per method and map it as a controller?

Comment: sounds like Struts. The horror..

Comment: @RiccardoFinazzi that is exactly what I intended to convey. That or use the, deprecated and soon (Spring 5) to be removed, [`MultiActionController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/multiaction/MultiActionController.html).